# How to format text within dreamweaver so it remains on one line?

Tags: html, dreamweaver

What I want to know is how do I stop my html code spreading over two lines it makes it very hard to read it.

I would like all of that

on one line for readability.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwpfs.png

Comment: Actual rendering should be in on line according to your screenshot. it's the dreamweaver editer that breaks the line when it reaches certain character. if the issue still persists open the html file in notepad and check if there are any <br> elements inserted into paragraph and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

try looking for a [word-wrap option](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/setting-coding-preferences.html) and turning it off,

Either that, or put in manual line-breaks in the [text](http://hipsum.co/), like this:

```
<p>
    Listicle pork belly Shoreditch Vice ethical Intelligentsia
    banjo, organic High Life direct trade cronut yr art party artisan.
    Direct trade pour-over pork belly aesthetic umami, hashtag 8-bit
    artisan gluten-free Godard Blue Bottle organic irony locavore.
</p>
```

This second option won't effect your HTML output and is even more readable as the text follows the HTML indenting and the lines are a sensible length long (content editors will thank you)